# Unity : instantiate object isn't created in intended location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

The rocket I create for my character isn't created in the fire point that is on the gun that is one the player. It's created on 0.314 on the world map. If the rocket in the hiervy it also spawns there.

Here's the code for the missile launcher:

```
[SerializeField] float fireRate = 0.3f;
[SerializeField] float rocketSpeed =15f;
[SerializeField] GameObject rocketType;
[SerializeField] Transform firePoint;
Player player;

Vector3 mousePos;
Camera mainCam;

void Start()
{
    player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    mainCam = FindObjectOfType<Camera>().GetComponent<Camera>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    mousePos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 aimDirection = (mousePos - transform.position).normalized*1;

    float aimAngle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDirection.y, aimDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg ;

    // Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(aimAngle, Vector3.forward);
    //  transform.rotation = rotation;
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, aimAngle);
    // transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, Vector3.forward, aimAngle);
    transform.position = player.transform.position + aimDirection;
}

public  void Fire()
{
    GameObject rocket = Instantiate(rocketType, firePoint.position,Quaternion.Euler(0,0, firePoint.rotation.z+90));
    rocket.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(firePoint.up * rocketSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}

public float GetFireRate()
{
    return fireRate;
}
```

[image]

The rocket (yellow circle) is in the spawn location.

I wanted the bullet to fly out of my character like a rocket.
[image]

[image]

Comment: it's a bit hard to ell where your player and where your missile are .. I think it would help to include two screenshots with having one of them selected in each ... as note though: what object is this script attached to? If it is a child of the `Player` anyway there shouldn't be a reason to actively move it via `transform.position` as it will already be moved whenever the `player` is moved

Comment: THE rocket luncher is a child of the player the fire point is the child of rocket luncher. if i changes the transfrom in the instatiat its only move it from the weird random spawn point.